# Ontouchstart is not working for svg element

Tags: svg, raphael

I am creating a circle using SVG

```
var gauge = mapSvg.circle(center['x'], center['y'], 85).attr({'stroke-width': 3, 'stroke': 'black', 'fill': 'white'});
```

It is in for loop, this circle created three times. I have added ontouchstart on its click

```
gauge.node.ontouchstart = function () { alert("hi>>>>>") }
```

but this alert is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
var r = Raphael("blah",200,200);

var c = r.circle(100,100,100).attr({fill: 'red' }).touchstart( function() { alert('hi') });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7c56E/

Comment: Its not working when I am creating this circle in loop with dynamic attribute. Its like only first refernce is used by touchstart

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle highlighting the problem, along with what device and browser you are using.

Comment: here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/7c56E/15/
I am testing on default browser in galaxy s2
thanks in advance.

Comment: Really it needs to be a working bit of code for people to experiment with the problem.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7c56E/18/
This problem is only occurring in Android Default Browser. In Android chrome and Android Mozilla its working fine. I am testing it in galaxy s2